# Cron job on Mac OS X Mavericks - Dropbox/GDrive Sync

Tags: macos, cron, osx-mavericks, dropbox, launchd

I would like to open everyday at a specific hour GDrive/Dropbox Application for approximately 30sec and kill them, in order to sync my files and extend my battery life.

Which way is the better to do that ? 
 Cron job in the terminal ? or LaunchCtl ?
 Or should I use a particular software ?

Comment: As your are using Mac OS, AppleScript may be the best way !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's the best way but I used a software called Cronnix (http://lifehacker.com/246565/download-of-the-day--cronnix-mac)

Then create a task : `open Dropbox` at a specific time and `pkill -9 "Dropbox"` a few minute later.

It did the trick but if you find a better solution you're open to share.